# How to do math operations in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have a query as following:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, COUNT(t.tahmin) AS tahmins_no, 
       SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings,
   SUM(t.result = 2) AS loses,
       (SUM(t.tahmin = 1)*1) AS ms1,
       (SUM(t.tahmin = 2)*3) AS ms0,
       (SUM(t.tahmin = 3)*1) AS ms2
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN tahminler t ON u.id = t.user_id 

GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING tahmins_no > 0
```

I want to make the `(SUM(t.tahmin = 1)*1) AS ms1` only calculated if `result = 1` (if result = 1 add to SUM else do not add)result is a value in the same record . Is that possible without making sub-query? I do not want to have complicated not optimized query.

Comment: Are you not getting the result you expect? The syntax you used is valid in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, COUNT(t.tahmin) AS tahmins_no, 
       SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings,
       SUM(t.result = 2) AS loses,
       (SUM((t.tahmin = 1)*(t.result = 1))*1) AS ms1,
       (SUM((t.tahmin = 2)*(t.result = 1))*3) AS ms0,
       (SUM((t.tahmin = 3)*(t.result = 1))*1) AS ms2
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     tahminler t
     ON u.id = t.user_id 
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING tahmins_no > 0;
```

You can also express this as case statements, for example:

```
sum(case when t.tahmin = 1 and t.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1 as ms1
```

Comment: that is exactly what I need . thank u very much . just small question is there a possible way to SUM all the values together ??

Comment: @Basel . . . I don't know what you mean, "sum all the values together".  Use either `sum()`, `+`, or a combination of the two.

Comment: I mean the sum of all sums can like (ms1+ms2+....+kg_yok) can i a result of aggregate functions together?

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE statement inside SUM function.

`SUM( CASE When t.Result=1 Then t.tahmin Else 0 end) As ms1`

Comment: That syntax `SUM(t.tahmin = 1)` is valid in MySQL since the expression evaluates as `TRUE` which is `1`, and works equivalently to `SUM(CASE WHEN t.tahmin = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski that is right. I want to calculate depending on the result value not the tahmin value .

Comment: @mhasan there is a multiplication operation in my question. It is like a weight so I should also use it . can I or can not?
also the t,tahmin is not always 1 it is also could be 2 or 3